# LY2NJ relay question

Tags: relay

I’m trying to use a LY2NJ relay to switch on an actuator when it gets a 1amp 240v signal.

Can someone explain how I would need to wire this?

The relay is rated at 240v 10a and is 8 pin.

I have 240v that I want to send to the actuator when the 1amp signal is triggered.

The 1amp signal is not enough to power the actuator on its own hence wanting to use a relay in the middle to send more power.

Comment: Relay and actuator data sheet links are required.

Comment: Relay has parameters for coil and for contacts. Which of them you mentioned?

Comment: Please include links to the relevant data sheets for the components and a circuit diagram.

Comment: LY is an (originally) Omron P/N for a smallish power relay. You need to tell us what you actually have, in the form of a complete part number and datasheet.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Likely [the circled rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIACZ.png) taken from [this datasheet](https://www.edata.omron.com.au/eData/Relays/LY_DS.pdf)?